# Когда нужно использовать конструктор без аргументов при сериализации?

Tags: java, конструктор, сериализация, десериализация

Не могу нагуглить ответ. Смысл в том, что иногда попытка сериализовать объект требует наличия пустого конструктора (а если его нет - выбрасывает исключение). Хочу разобраться, когда нужны эти конструкторы, и зачем. Пример задачи:

```
import java.io.*;


public class Solution implements Serializable {
    public static class A {

        protected String nameA = "A";

        public A(String nameA) {
            this.nameA += nameA;
        }

        public A() {      // пустой бессмысленный конструктор? Зачем?
        }
    }

    public class B extends A implements Serializable {

        public B() {      // тот же вопрос
        }

        private String nameB;


        public B(String nameA, String nameB) {
            super(nameA);
            this.nameA += nameA;
            this.nameB = nameB;
        }

        private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
            out.writeObject(nameA);
            out.defaultWriteObject();
        }

        private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            nameA = (String) in.readObject();
            in.defaultReadObject();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(arrayOutputStream);

        Solution solution = new Solution();
        B b = solution.new B("B2", "C33");
        System.out.println("nameA: " + b.nameA + ", nameB: " + b.nameB);

        oos.writeObject(b);

        ByteArrayInputStream arrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(arrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(arrayInputStream);

        B b1 = (B) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println("nameA: " + b1.nameA + ", nameB: " + b1.nameB);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пустой конструктор необходим для восстановления объекта. Всякий раз когда вы определяете хотя бы один конструктор с параметрами (т.е. по дефолту не создается пустой конструктор.

Это позволяет восстанавливать сериализованный объект из потока, т.е. начать не дожидаясь получения всего объекта. Сериализованный объект начинается с описания класса. Читается описание и создается пустой объект. Для этого класс и должен иметь пустой конструктор. Потом идут параметры, если есть. Они последовательно читаются и вставляются в созданный объект (через сеттеры, ведь наверное речь идет о `javabean`).

Вторая причина - при сериализации пустые параметры (параметр = `null`) просто не пишутся в поток, т.е. минимизируется размер сериализованного обьекта.

Comment: спасибо за подробный ответ